# Interaction between service and activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am creating an app in android, and i am stuck at a point wherein I want to send real-time data from an activity class to my background service at frequent intervals.

For firing the service from my activity at frequent intervals, I have used PendingIntent along with BroadcastReceiver.

Answer (score 2):

proper way for this kind of communication is [Service binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services). under link you have some samples how to do it

another (easier) way is to use some IPC event bus, most popular is probably [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)